# Getting actual type of Option[Any]

Tags: scala, reflection

I have the following code:

```
case class Property(name: String, value: Option[Any])

class PropertyType[+T <: Any: ru.TypeTag] {
  def isValidType(property: Property): Boolean = {
    property.value match {
      case None => true
      case Some(value) => ru.typeOf[T] == getTypeTag(value)
    }
  }

  private def getTypeTag[TT: ru.TypeTag](obj: TT) = ru.typeTag[TT]
}

case object StringPropertyType extends PropertyType[String]
```

Of course, StringPropertyType.isValidType(Property("test", Some("test))) returns false, because getTypeTag(Property.value.get) returns Any.

I wonder how I could make it works, because getClass on value returns String:

```
scala> Property("test", Some("test")).value.get.getClass
res4: Class[_] = class java.lang.String
```

How can i get the actual value type of Option[Any].get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You trying to compare `Type` and `TypeTag`
2. Scala runtime reflection info provided by compiler, so you need to add this type information to `Property`

`import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}`

```
case class Property[T](name: String, value: Option[T])

class PropertyType[+T <: Any: ru.TypeTag] {
  def isValidType[S: ru.TypeTag](property: Property[S]): Boolean = {
    property.value match {
      case None => true
      case Some(value) => ru.typeTag[S].tpe <:< ru.typeOf[T]
    }
  }
}

case object StringPropertyType extends PropertyType[String]

println(StringPropertyType.isValidType(Property("test", Some("test")))) // true
```